# Nested Let in Anglican Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am new to Anglican, the Probabilistic programming language in Clojure. I am trying to use a nested let construct in Clojure.

The following `defquery`runs without any issues.

```
(defquery panda3 [p1]
  (let [p2 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:speA (/ 1 2),
                 :speB (/ 1 2)}))]
    (if (= p2 :speA)
      ( let [p3 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:twins (/ 1 10),
                 :notwins (/ 9 10)}))] 

      )
      ( let [p3 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:twins (/ 2 10),
                 :notwins (/ 8 10)}))]

      ))

    p2))
```

However, instead of returning the value of `p2` at the end, if I try to return the value of `p3`, it returns errors.

```
(defquery panda3 [p1]
  (let [p2 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:speA (/ 1 2),
                 :speB (/ 1 2)}))]
    (if (= p2 :speA)
      ( let [p3 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:twins (/ 1 10),
                 :notwins (/ 9 10)}))] 

      )
      ( let [p3 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:twins (/ 2 10),
                 :notwins (/ 8 10)}))]

      ))

    p3))
```

The idea is to assign p3 based on the outcome of p2. However, I am unable to do so. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `let` defines local variables that are available in the body of the `let`.  Where you are trying to return `p3`, `p3` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, you need to return `p3` from within the scope of the `let` in which it is defined:

```
(defquery panda3 [p1]
  (let [p2 (sample 
              (categorical
                {:speA (/ 1 2),
                 :speB (/ 1 2)}))]
    (if (= p2 :speA)
      (let [p3 (sample 
                 (categorical
                   {:twins (/ 1 10),
                    :notwins (/ 9 10)}))] 
        p3)
      (let [p3 (sample 
                 (categorical
                   {:twins (/ 2 10),
                    :notwins (/ 8 10)}))]
        p3 ))))
```

---

***Update***

As amalloy points out, the 2nd part could be:

```
  ; return the result of `(sample (categorical ...))` called
  ; with one of the 2 maps
  (if (= p2 :speA)
    (sample 
      (categorical
        {:twins (/ 1 10),
         :notwins (/ 9 10)} ))
    (sample 
      (categorical
        {:twins (/ 2 10),
         :notwins (/ 8 10)} )))
```

or even

```
  ; return the result of `(sample (categorical ...))` called
  ; with one of the 2 maps
  (sample 
    (categorical
      (if (= p2 :speA)
        {:twins (/ 1 10),
         :notwins (/ 9 10)}
        {:twins (/ 2 10),
         :notwins (/ 8 10)} )))
```

Comment: Better: `(let [p3 (sample (categorical (if ...)))] ...)`